# Paper.js not drawing shapes

Tags: javascript, paperjs

so I'am trying to draw a shape every time user press a key, however i get weird console error.

```
paper-full.js:14632 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier directly after number (8:42)
at t (paper-full.js:14632)
at E (paper-full.js:14632)
at y (paper-full.js:14632)
at g (paper-full.js:14632)
at U (paper-full.js:14632)
at z (paper-full.js:14632)
at ue (paper-full.js:14632)
at oe (paper-full.js:14632)
at ae (paper-full.js:14632)
at te (paper-full.js:14632)
```

I'am not familiar with paper.js. My html, script code seems to be correct, and if someone would drop a helping hand it would be a big relief.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sounds of keyboard</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.10.3/paper-full.js"></script>

 <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
  var circles = [];

  function onKeyDown(event){
   var maxPoint = new Point(view.size.width, view.size.height);
   var randomPoint = Point.random();
   var point = maxPoint * randomPoint;
   var newCircle = new Path.Circle(point, 5oo);
   newCircle.fillColor = "orange";
   circles.push(newCircle);
  }

  function onFrame(event){
  for(var i=0; i<circles.length; i++){
  circles[i].fillColor.hue += 1;
  circles[i].scale(.9);
  }
  }


 </script>
</head>
<body>


<canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By replacing `new Path.Circle(point, 5oo)` to `new Path.Circle(point, 500)`, it works :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sounds of keyboard</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.10.3/paper-full.js"></script>

 <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
  var circles = [];

  function onKeyDown(event){
   var maxPoint = new Point(view.size.width, view.size.height);
   var randomPoint = Point.random();
   var point = maxPoint * randomPoint;
   var newCircle = new Path.Circle(point, 500);
   newCircle.fillColor = "orange";
   circles.push(newCircle);
  }

  function onFrame(event){
  for(var i=0; i<circles.length; i++){
  circles[i].fillColor.hue += 1;
  circles[i].scale(.9);
  }
  }


 </script>
</head>
<body>


<canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```